# Updating to Angular 9 via CLI - devkit/core and devkit/schematics are not updated

Tags: angular

If this question has been asked somewhere else, then I'm sorry for asking it again - I've searched and couldn't find an answer that matches my specific scenario.

So I've just updated my Angular project to version 9, and I didn't get any failures. However, when I run ng --version, I'm seing some information that worries me:
[image: local project ng --version]

Specifically the @angular-devkit/core and @angular-devkit/schematics, which are listed as version 7.3.10.

I would expect these to be version 9 for my project, so I tried to run a version check in another folder, to check my angular CLI global versions:

[image: global ng --version]

As you can see, in my global check, I have the expected version 9.1.8 of both @angular-devkit/core and @angular-devkit/schematics.

Any idea what could cause my local project to not update these? As I understand, the devkit packages are under packades of @angular-devkit/build-angular, so I would expect these to be updated, when I update that package, but it doesn't seem like it.

Would really appreciate if anyone has experience with this, or have a suggestion for what I can do to update my project local versions of these packages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Updating from version 7/8 to `Angular 9` is a bit tricky. Get to latest version of `Angular 8` first, Then move up to Angular 9. At least this is how I upgraded mine.

Comment: Part of the update process to 9, is to upgrade to Angular 8 (https://update.angular.io/#8.2:9.0l3), but this doesn't seem to have updated the devkit packages

Comment: So I now got the correct version listed when running ng --version. I did this by manually installing the 2 packages - I'm just worried that this could cause some issues, or I'm not doing stuff in the correct order maybe?

Comment: Instead of upgrading consider creating a new v9 project from scratch and then move over your code to the new project (or use the newly generated `package.json`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm closing this question - I did get a version match by manually adding these packages, but in the end, it didn't really change the core issue I was experiencing - I suspect that my project hasn't had the correct update process somewhere along the version history.

But if people look to this question for answers, you can manually npm install specific versions of these packages, if they are added in your package.json

Comment: when you added these packages manually, they updated your package.json file. Right? But by default, these packages are part of node modules yet not visible in package.json. Now since you have added these packages manually, they stay mentioned in package.json forever even though thats not the default. Is that correct?